Definition of a projective module
Let $R$ be a unital ring and $P$ an $R$-$R$-bimodule that is (fgp) finitely-generated projective as a left $R$-module. FGP implies that (is equivalent to in fact) the fact that we have a dual basis $e_i,e^i$ for $P$, where $e^i$ is a basis of the space of left $R$-module maps from $P$ to $R$, which we denote by ${}^*P$.
As is "well-known" this means that we have a bimodule map
$$
R \to {}^*P \otimes_R P, ~ 1 \mapsto c := \sum_i e^i \otimes e_i.
$$
Since this is a claimed to be a bimodule map $c$ must be a central element of $P \otimes P^*$. In other words
$$
rc = cr  ~~~ \textrm{ for all } r \in R.
$$
Unfortunately I cannot see why this is true!

Does FGP not imply free here?

No why should it?

We can identify ${}^\ast P\otimes_RP$ with $\mathrm{End}({}_RP)$, so the set of endomorphisms of $P$ as a left $R$-module. This sends $f\otimes p$ to the endomorphism $q\mapsto f(q)p$.
Now, the element $c=\sum e^i\otimes e_i$ corresponds to the identity on $P$, in which case both $rc$ and $cr$ correspond to right multiplication by $r\in R$. Thus $rc=cr$.

Thanks for the nice explanation! One question though, what does the inverse of the map $p \mapsto f(q)p$ look like?

An endomorphism $\theta$ of ${}_RP$ is sent to $\sum e^i\otimes\theta(e_i)$ in ${}^\ast P\otimes P$. To see this one uses that $c$ corresponds to the identity, so $p=\sum e^i(p)e_i$ for all $p$.
